# When we using the % and px for width of table's tr.Which is the high priority?

Tags: html, css, html-table

These days I using the table to render the data from server. But there are a lot of columns.So Ishould set a fixed width to some columns. But the page is responsive,when the page show in the big screen, some columns will be responsive. I write the code as follow. I just show four columns here.

```
 <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td width="100px">ID</td>
        <td width="100px">Publish Time</td>
        <td width="20%">Description</td>
        <td width="20%">Operation</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

But I think the "100px" cann't apply the td. The result is confusing. So when we mix using the "px" and "%",the "%" is higher priority than "px".

Comment: This is invalid HTML, you should use `style="width:XXX(px|%)"` instead of `width="XXX(px|%)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I think the "100px" cann't apply the td.

Depends on whether `table-layout` is `fixed` or `auto`.  It is the latter by default.  If fixed, it will use the set pixel widths.  If auto, it will use the percentage widths.  As such it's not a great idea to combine the `auto` layout with fixed widths if the table itself is not a fixed width.

- layout: auto, http://jsfiddle.net/w2Pxn/

  - Last two take 20% of width.  Remainders adjust accordingly (40% each) except at very low total width.
- layout: fixed, http://jsfiddle.net/w2Pxn/1/

  - First two columns are set at 100px width.  Last two columns use the remaining width proportionally.
  - http://jsfiddle.net/w2Pxn/2/ -- example with double the percentge width in the last column.

---

Incidentally, [`<td>`](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/td) has no width attribute.  You should be using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The rules on how it works out what happens when is defined here: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html

e.g

> 17.5.2.2 Automatic table layout
>
> In this algorithm (which generally requires no more than two passes),
>   the table's width is given by the width of its columns (and
>   intervening borders). This algorithm reflects the behavior
>   of several popular HTML user agents at the writing of this
>   specification. UAs are not required to implement this algorithm to
>   determine the table layout in the case that
>   'table-layout' is 'auto'; they can
>   use any other algorithm even if it results in different behavior.
>
> Input to the automatic table layout must only include the width of the
>   containing block and the content of, and any CSS properties set on,
>   the table and any of its descendants.
>
> ***Note.** This may be defined in more detail in CSS3.*
>
> *The remainder of this section is non-normative.*
>
> This algorithm may be inefficient since it requires the user agent to
>   have access to all the content in the table before determining the
>   final layout and may demand more than one pass.
>
> Column widths are determined as follows:
>
> 1. Calculate the minimum content width (MCW) of each cell: the formatted content may span any number of lines but may not overflow
>      the cell box. If the specified 'width'
>      (W) of the cell is greater than MCW, W is the minimum cell width. A
>      value of 'auto' means that MCW is the minimum cell width.
>
>    Also, calculate the "maximum" cell width of each cell: formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line
>      breaks occur.
> 2. For each column, determine a maximum and minimum column width from the cells that span only that column. The minimum is that required by
>      the cell with the largest minimum cell width (or the column
>      'width', whichever is larger). The
>      maximum is that required by the cell with the largest maximum cell
>      width (or the column 'width', whichever
>      is larger).
> 3. For each cell that spans more than one column, increase the minimum widths of the columns it spans so that together, they are at
>      least as wide as the cell. Do the same for the maximum widths. If
>      possible, widen all spanned columns by approximately the same amount.
> 4. For each column group element with a 'width' other than 'auto', increase the minimum widths of the columns it spans, so that together
>      they are at least as wide as the column group's 'width'.
>
> This gives a maximum and minimum width for each column.
>
> The caption width minimum (CAPMIN) is determined by calculating for
>   each caption the minimum caption outer width as the MCW of a
>   hypothetical table cell that contains the caption formatted as
>   "display: block". The greatest of the minimum caption outer widths is
>   CAPMIN.
>
> Column and caption widths influence the final table width as follows:
>
> 1. If the 'table' or 'inline-table' element's 'width' property has a computed value
>      (W) other than 'auto', the used width is the greater of W, CAPMIN, and
>      the minimum width required by all the columns plus cell spacing or
>      borders (MIN). If the used width is greater than MIN, the extra width
>      should be distributed over the columns.
> 2. If the 'table' or 'inline-table' element has 'width: auto', the used width is the greater of the table's containing block width,
>      CAPMIN, and MIN. However, if either CAPMIN or the maximum width
>      required by the columns plus cell spacing or borders (MAX) is less
>      than that of the containing block, use max(MAX, CAPMIN).
>
> A percentage value for a column width is relative to the table width.
>   If the table has 'width: auto', a percentage represents a constraint
>   on the column's width, which a UA should try to satisfy. (Obviously,
>   this is not always possible: if the column's width is '110%', the
>   constraint cannot be satisfied.)
>
> ***Note.** In this algorithm, rows (and row groups) and columns (and column groups) both constrain and are constrained by the dimensions of
>   the cells they contain. Setting the width of a column may indirectly
>   influence the height of a row, and vice versa.*

Comment: Maybe you can update your answer to explain which parts of the spec apply to his specific question

Answer (score 0):

In html markup you cannot apply the width in pixels but can apply percentage. So `<td width="20%">` works but not `<td width="100px">`

And as per my experience table-layouts are supported in percentage better way than other elements